# OpenGL - reproducing a transparency effect from a black background to a white one

Tags: android, graphics, opengl-es

My program uses blending via `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE)` to make a pleasent effect when the background is set to black with `clearColor(0,0,0,1)`. When 
the background is set to white with `clearColor(1,1,1,1)` the screen is blank white. I don't know how to generate the same trasparency effect on the white background. Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: do you know how it works? GL_ONE just adds color values together. if you want to achieve the same with white, then your colors would have to be reduced from the white color (instead of adding), so you would see dark holes instead of bright holes. is this what you want?

Comment: I really don't know how it works, I was just messing around with parameters and came up with something I like. I think I'd like to see bright holes. Do you know which arguments to pass into glBlendFunc to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE)` roughly translates into the following equation (the clamping happens at another place, technically)

```
New_Framebuffer_Value :=
    New_Red   := min(1, Incoming_Red   * Incoming_Alpha + Previous_Framebuffer_Red   )
    New_Green := min(1, Incoming_Green * Incoming_Alpha + Previous_Framebuffer_Green )
    New_Blue  := min(1, Incoming_Blue  * Incoming_Alpha + Previous_Framebuffer_Blue  )
```

However if you cleared to while, the `Previous_Framebuffer_{Red,Green,Blue}` are already at 1.0 and so all following will be clamped.

So you need to modulate not only the incoming fragments, but also the previous ones:

```
New_Framebuffer_Value :=
    New_Red   := min(1, Incoming_Red   * Incoming_Alpha + Previous_Framebuffer_Red   * ( 1 - Incoming_Alpha ) )
    New_Green := min(1, Incoming_Green * Incoming_Alpha + Previous_Framebuffer_Green * ( 1 - Incoming_Alpha ) )
    New_Blue  := min(1, Incoming_Blue  * Incoming_Alpha + Previous_Framebuffer_Blue  * ( 1 - Incoming_Alpha ) )
```

which is done by  `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)`

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. The arguments you listed look good, and they were the first thing I tried, but the effect isn't quite the same. When my program had the black background and lots of green particles overlapping, it looked light yellow, and this effect isnt replicated with what you listed. But its still good and it's what I'll use.

Comment: @farm ostrich: Those particles were probably not perfectly green (R=0, B=0), but had some nonzero red component. And through this additive blending the Green channel did saturate (it clamped at 1), and the further incoming particles would incrementally increase the red value, until that one would saturate, too. This effect is impossible to retain if you want to blend additively over a white background. An interim solution would be rendering the particles to a texture and using the intensity as inverse alpha, overlaying that over the other picture; the particle will get dark halos though.

Answer (score 2):

There's not a lot of information here, but I'd suggest trying `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)`.  This is the most "typical" blend mode for achieving alpha blending.  Each color value in the source pixel is multiplied by the source pixel's alpha value, and added to destination pixel's color value multiplied by, well, one minus the source pixel's alpha.

This would work the same as the quoted blend mode on a black background, but introduce the correct "amount" of the background color as it shifted away from black.